# How to Extract Multiple Columns from Excel into an array

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlrd

I am using **xlrd** to extract individual columns. I am hoping to extract multiple columns from excel into an array so I can use itertools group by function to analyze them.

Is it possible to pull more than one column from excel using **xlrd**?

Comment: The short answer I think is yes, but do you have any example code?

Comment: I was hoping there would be a generic method for this. I could not find any general way to import multiple columns. I have code to import single columns, but that is not what I am going for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you,
Click [python documentation for xlrd](https://pythonhosted.org/xlrd3/sheet.html)!

```
Sheet.row_slice(rowx, start_colx=0, end_colx=None)
Returns a slice of the Cell objects in the given row.
```

You might just need to loop over it